# Ruby 2.0.0 doesn't work after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pik

I originally had Ruby 1.9.3 installed on my window box but I need to run a Ruby 2.0.0 app so I installed pik and use it to switch between 2 different versions of Ruby.

I was able to switch between the 2 versions but when I attempted to run my Ruby 2.0.0 app, it doesn't work. I might had broken something when I was changing the PATH. Or do i need to install other gems to supplement Ruby 2.0.0? Any help, thought is appreciated. 
(I installed my Ruby on Rails using the RailsyInstaller for Window. That was why I had Ruby 1.9.3.)

Details:

Location of pik: C:\pik

User PATH before attempting to set Ruby 2.0.0 as default Ruby version:
 **C:\pik;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\Users\tina\AppData\Roaming\npm;**

Changed PATH to:
**C:\pik;C:\RailsInstaller\Git\cmd;C:\RailsInstaller\DevKit;C:\Users\tina.pik\rubies\Ruby-200-p195\bin;C:\Users\tina\AppData\Roaming\npm;**

I was able to run my Ruby 1.9.3 apps with Ruby 1.9.3, but when I attempted to run a Ruby 2.0.0 app with Ruby 2.0.0 it threw me the error below:

[image: Error with 'Bundle Install' and 'Rails s']

Comment: Don't worry. Run `gem list` and you will find out that you have to reinstall your gems.